# How to get div that fired event if i have function onclick on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given this HTML code:

```
<td role-id="@Model.Id">
    @Model.Name
    <div class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit update_user' onclick='UpdateRole()'></div>
</td>
```

I need to retrieve `role-id` when clicking on the div.

JS code:

```
function UpdateRole() {
    $("#ModalUser").show();
    var role_id = $(this).parent().attr("role-id");
    var user_id = $(this).parent().parent().attr("user-id");
    console.log(role_id);
    console.log(user_id);
};
```

Both values are `undefined`, how can I get `role-id` without this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better approach is to use `jQuery` event binding, but using your approach, pass `this` context from called function:

**Problem:** In your example, `this` is not the `element` on which event is invoked but `window`!

```js
function UpdateRole(that) {
  $("#ModalUser").show();
  var role_id = $(that).parent().attr("role-id");
  var user_id = $(that).parent().parent().attr("user-id");
  console.log(role_id);
  console.log(user_id);
};
```

```html
<td role-id="@Model.Id">
  @Model.Name
  <div class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit update_user' onclick='UpdateRole(this)'></div>
</td>
```

**Using `jQuery` `event-binding`:**

```js
function UpdateRole() {
  $("#ModalUser").show();
  var role_id = $(this).parent().attr("role-id");
  var user_id = $(this).parent().parent().attr("user-id");
  console.log(role_id);
  console.log(user_id);
}
$('.update_user').on('click', UpdateRole);
```

```html
<td role-id="@Model.Id">
  @Model.Name
  <div class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit update_user' onclick='UpdateRole(this)'></div>
</td>
```

Comment: Again, I see no reason for this to have recieved a -1?

Answer (score 1):

You should register your event using jQuery, this makes it much easier to find the calling element:

```
$('.update_user').click(UpdateRole);
```

You can now:

```
function UpdateRole() {
    var clickedElement = $(this);
    $("#ModalUser").show();
    var role_id = clickedElement.parent().attr("role-id");
    var user_id = clickedElement.parent().parent().attr("user-id");
    console.log(role_id);
    console.log(user_id);
};
```

Comment: What's the -1 for?

Answer (score -1):

this is very simple you need to update  this line with . data-* is html5 new attribute for setting and getting data

```
$(".update_user").on("click",function(){
  elm=$(this).parent().data("role-id");
   elm // this element consist of role id, now you can use this variable
});
```

Comment: This is wrong. data is for reading data- attributes. He doesn't have a data attribute

Comment: But he can create data attribute. there is no harm of using data attributes